# How to hide the main scrollbar of the screen using Tailwind CSS? I am using Next Js 14

Tags: tailwind-css, next.js13

I want to hide the scrollbar on my project screen. Not just any random elements scrollbar, but the scrollbar of the entire screen. How to do that? I am using Next Js 14, Tailwind 3.3.0.

I have searched my problem on search engines and came across two different methods. But none of those worked.

1. In Tailwind.config.js

```
plugins: [
    function ({ addUtilities }) {
      const newUtilities = {
        /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
        ".no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar": {
          display: "none",
        },
        /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
        ".no-scrollbar": {
          "-ms-overflow-style": "none" /* IE and Edge */,
          "scrollbar-width": "none" /* Firefox */,
        },
      };
      addUtilities(newUtilities)
    },
    nextui(),
  ],
```

2. In Global.css file

```
@layer utilities {
  /* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
  .no-scrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
  }
 /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
  .no-scrollbar {
      -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
      scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
}
```

These method worked for any other div element, but what I want to do here is to apply it to the whole body, so that the main scrollbar of the screen dissapears but the contents remain scrollable. I have tried applying the "no-scrollable" class to app/layout.js, app/page.js as well. I don't know what went wrong.

Comment: `html, body { @apply no-scrollbar }`